# varnish + Turpentine issue

Tags: magento-1.7, varnish, turpentine

```
My OS: Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail
Varnish: varnish-3.0.4 revision 9f83e8f 
nginx version: nginx/1.4.3
Magento: 1.7.0.2
nginx port: 8080
varnish port: 80
turpentine: installed via connect
the authentication key is correct
```

After a clean install, my headers for the magento homepage have varnish specific headers:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2013 08:42:45 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Server: nginx/1.4.3
Age: 0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.5-1+debphp.org~raring+1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
X-Varnish: 615557293
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3176
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

I then generate and apply the Turpentine vcl via cache management, and the headers change to:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2013 08:44:05 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: nginx/1.4.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.5-1+debphp.org~raring+1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

my /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}
```

my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen          8080;
  server_name     domain.co.uk www.domain.co.uk;
  index           index.php index.html;
  root            /path/to/site/htdocs;

  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/.htpasswd;

  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
  }
  location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

magento caching options:

```
Layouts DISABLED
Blocks HTML output  DISABLED
Varnish Pages ENABLED
Varnish ESI Blocks  ENABLED
```

server setup

I'm hoping its something obvious, but any help appreciated.

the generated vcl from turpentine:

```
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx-%04lx-%04lx-%04lx-%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
}
sub remove_cache_headers {
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
}
sub remove_double_slashes {
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2");
}
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ,
"\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:",
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 3600;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP,
"\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:",
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
return (pipe);
}
call remove_double_slashes;
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|ad|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "mobile";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "msie";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Firefox") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "firefox";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Safari") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "safari";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Chrome") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "chrome";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Opera") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "opera";
} else {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "other";
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/getBlock/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed";
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=") {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
call generate_session;
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
return (lookup);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
return (lookup);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (hash);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_fetch {
set req.grace = 15s;
if (req.url ~ "^(/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
call remove_cache_headers;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
} elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
call generate_session_expires;
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

Comment: When i check my headers, they aren't any different and still my content is cached, check varnishhist in your cli and look at your varnish logs.

Comment: May be a late answer, but comment out
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;

Answer (score 2):

I once spent an hour trying to work out why pretty much same setup as yours was working on dev server, but not staging server.

Use `varnishadm`'s `vcl.list` and `vcl.show` to make sure the Turpentine VCL is actually loaded.

Mine wasn't.